# JavaScript toggle function and fill SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm pretty new in coding JavaScript and I need help for this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/n1r64mdo/1/).

```
<script>
    function OnOff() {
        var element = document.getElementById("")
        element.classList.toggle("")
    }
</script>
```

I want to change the fill property when I click the on off button.

If I click the button one time I light the bulb otherwise I turn it off.

Comment: you need to toggle the class for the Tracciato_1. Also remove the fill attribute of the Tracciato_1.  Set the fill in CSS

Comment: And on top of that you have some typos, onlick="OnOff" should be onclick="OnOff()" on the `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your a tag with this. I fixed some typo.

```
<a class="button" onclick="OnOff()">On/Off</a>
```

2)Add this class in your css file

```
.change-color {
  fill: #000000;
}
```

3. Finally change your script like this :)

```
<script>
  function OnOff() {
    var element = document.getElementById("Tracciato_1")
    element.classList.toggle("change-color");
  }
</script>
```

if you  will have a question you can ask .